# Play Framework 2.6 not working fine in intelij Idea 2016.3.6

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

Any Ideas to fix this problem

[image]

program was compile and working fine but there are some issue in code suggestion in editor

Comment: is the project imported as a play framework application?

Comment: yes I was import it as a SBT project

Comment: I would close the project and delete .idea folder and try to reopen the project.

Comment: no dude I clean all of file created by intelij-idea and re import as a SBT project but it is give same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is few step to fix this problem

1. Update Intelij Idea (2017.2.1) to latest version without importing previous version settings
2. run `rm -rvf .idea/ .sbtServer/ project/project/ project/target target`
3. import projet idea as SBT module
4. then restart intelij idea

Enjoy!